# atom-typescript complaining about tsconfig.json--how can I automatically create one?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I just started playing with the "atom-typescript" plugin as referenced here:

[Getting Started With TypeScript](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html)

The page states that to utilize atom-typescript, we literally just need to:

> Now create a new .ts TypeScript file and start hacking away. AtomTS will take care of compiling it to .js and create a default tsconfig.json TypeScript project file for you.

This is *not* the case as I've created a simple directory structure and when attempting to build any *.ts file receive the following error:

[image: No project file found. Please use the 'Create tsconfig.json profile file' command]

The error states I need to utilize the 'Create tsconfig.json project file' command--I simply cannot locate this command.

I understand I can create the file manually but I would like to know if / where the file can be created automatically.  Thanks!

Comment: If you type `cmd(ctrl)+shift+p` and then `tsconfig` I believe the command should appear.

Comment: Jesse--thank you, that worked perfectly!  Can you please supply this as the answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Type `cmd(ctrl)+shift+p` to bring up the list of commands and then `tsconfig` to find the command to generate the `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 12):

install typescript,then excute "tsc --init" command in shell.
will generate tsconfig.json file.