# How to create the config files ( tsconfig.json, typings.json, package.json)?

Tags: angular

I can copy these files from the https://angular.io/guide/quickstart.

But I would like to know more about these files.

How can we create it manually?

From where I can know more about these files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**package.json**

includes information about packages and libraries which are used by your project,
also can include `npm scripts` which helps of running tasks of application like running tests, building js and so on...

`npm init` to init new package.json file

docs:
[npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

**tsconfig.json**

provides information about compiling process `typescript` into `javascript`. In which version should be compiled ts, should js files include source maps, and such information usually described in this file.

`tsc --init` to init new tsconfig.json file

docs: [tsconfig docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

**typings.json**

includes references to definition type files for the external library, it helps your app to be more intellisense. If you are writing types for your application you need to know about types of other libraries you use.

`typings init` to init new typings.json file (should be installed globally or locally)

More info:

[typings package](https://github.com/typings/typings) (helps to generate typings.json file and save dependencies to it)

[types defenitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) (Database of type definitions for libraries)

[full tsconfig scheme](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig)

Hope it will help you!

Comment: i had gone through the link of tsconfig docs.
Still cant find out any thing about.
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
Can you ?

Comment: added full tsconfig scheme, you can find description of each property, for example: `experimentalDecorators` - Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. And after you can find in google what is  ES7 decorators: [decorators](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.n0sjfih2s)

Comment: Update your answer about tsconfig.json: install typescript,then excute "tsc --init" command in shell. will generate tsconfig.json file. From http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577329/3914072

Comment: The tsconfig link is broken.

Comment: @recursive, fixed

Answer (score 2):

In [TypeScript 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/), `typings.json` is **not** necessary.

> Getting and using declaration files in 2.0 is much easier. To get declarations for a library like lodash, all you need is npm:

```
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

You can install typings as:

```
npm i -S @types/core-js @types/jasmine @types/node
```

The packages.json will add:

```
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.2",
"@types/node": "^8.5.2",
```